# Fraction of probability terms

Tags: probability

I repost the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4042306/determine-of-the-value-of-the-quantity-given-the-variables-are-discrete-and-rand), since it has been deleted.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be independent events in a probability space which are
> each less than certain. Determine the value of the following quantity.
> \begin{align*}
>      \frac{1 - P(A \cup B)}{(1 - P(A))(1 - P(B))} \end{align*}

I hope you find this question interesting as well.

Comment: I don't see why the problem is interesting.  In the absence of any explanation from you why it is interesting, important, or difficult, I'm inclined to close it.  Please use the body of the Question not only to give a self-contained problem statement (the setup and goal of the problem), but also to put it in enough context for Readers to tell whether you have digested the problem statement.  In particular does the meaning of "independent events" need to be explained, or do you know the definition but need help applying it here.

Comment: @hardmath If posted a answer. So yes I have digested the problem statement. I just reposted the problem. Is there any problem? Edit: The question has been closed, for what reason ever. In general in many cases I cannot comprehend why some questions are closed and why some questions are not closed. I´ve given up to think that there is any system behind.

Comment: I have upvoted your solution because you make a couple of points that are missing or brushed over in the other Answers.  But the Question itself lacks even the context that was present in the original version.  Presumably your interest in the problem is quite different from that of the seventh grader who originally asked.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for voting. I just found the question interesting. So my intention was that other users can take note of this question. With the two additional answers it makes the repost more reasonable, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another, and a slightly faster way would be using the fact that if two events are independent, then their complements are also independent. Also, note that $P((A \cup B)^c)=P(A^c \cap B^c)$ by De Morgan’s. Then the fraction simplifies quite easily:
$$
\frac{1 - P(A \cup B)}{(1 - P(A))(1 - P(B))}=\frac{P(A^c \cap B^c)}{P(A^c)P(B^c)}=\frac{P(A^c) P(B^c)}{P(A^c)P(B^c)}=1,
$$
by independence of $A^c$ and $B^c.$

Answer (score 2):

We should know that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$,

where $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$, if $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

So we replace $P(A\cup B)$ and multiply out the brackets at the denominator. Finally we compare the terms at the numerator and at the denominator.

$$\begin{align*}
   \ldots= \frac{1 - P(A)-P(B)+P(A)\cdot P(B)}{(1 - P(A))(1 - P(B))}=\frac{1 - P(A)-P(B)+P(A)\cdot P(B)}{1-P(B)-P(A)+P(A)\cdot P(B)}=1
\end{align*}
$$

Moreover the exercise tells us that the events $A$ and $B$ are in probability space which are each less than certain. That means that $P(A),P(B)<1\Rightarrow 1-P(A),1-P(B)>0$. So the denominator is not zero, which is a necessary condition for a valid fraction.

Answer (score 1):

You can reason this out in words. The numerator is the probability that neither event occurs. So is the denominator, since the events are independent. So the quotient is $1$.